# disqus comment box not showing for posts

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

I am facing problem with disqus comment box .It is not displaying for [old & new posts](https://nithiias.com/hyderabad-advantage-2019/).I have checked "Allow Comments" & "Allow trackbacks & pingbacks on this page" .In screen options too "Discussion" is marked .In setting->Discussion->Default article settings all the options are checked.Under advanced tab of plugin,checkbox is enabled to render of javascript on posts.On site, it's not showing default wordpress comment box too.I am using Islemag theme.I am not getting why it is happening so.I made a bit changes in my single.php "Single Post " file

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <?php
        $archive_content_classes = apply_filters( 'islemag_archive_content_classes', array( 'islemag-content-left', 'col-md-9' ) );
        ?>
        <div 

        <?php
        if ( ! empty( $archive_content_classes ) ) {
            echo 'class="' . implode( ' ', $archive_content_classes ) . '"'; }   ?> >//closing of div tag
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
                comments_template();   
                endwhile; 
            ?>
            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Would be thankful for any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem,can try to troubleshoot their plugins.This method solved my problem.I tried to deactivate all the plugins.Then activated disqus plugin, after that one by one activate the other plugins, to check to know the conflicting plugin due to which comment box wasn't appearing for the posts.
For more reference [check here](https://help.disqus.com/troubleshooting/wordpress-troubleshooting-and-faq)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure it out why comment form is not displaying on some posts but not all. But the reason was "Automatically close comments on articles" checkbox is checked on settings -> discussion in WP admin panel. Hope this will be helpful for someone in the future.